# Is it possible to enable underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys?

Tags: keyboard

There is a very convenient feature in Windows that underlines keyboard shortcuts such as in the image below. If I want to select Action, I can just press Alt+a; Refresh Alt+f; and so forth. The underlines appear in Microsoft apps, installers so I can just press alt+n for next instead of using my cursor, etc. It is really wonderful and I miss it. Is it possible to get something like that in OSX because I hate using my mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

macOS does have keyboard shortcuts, but they do not display with underlined letters. Many menu items will display their shortcut to the right. Some menu items will not have a shortcut.

[image: Chrome's File menu with hotkeys to the right]

If the menu item doesn't have a shortcut, you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to open a search bar that will let you type in the command. You can arrow down and hit return to activate that menubar item.

[image: Help menu with search bar]

You can also arrow through the menu bar by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>). You may need to toggle this on with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.